# Permissions of parent directory (being able to write on it, but not deleting it)

Tags: permissions

I'm interested in protecting a parent directory (e.g., `test` in the example below) by being removed (i.e., accidentally, without explicit root priviledges), while at the same time I need to be able to write inside it (as a non-root user).

For instance, suppose that we have a parent directory `test` with the following sub-directories:

```
test/
|-- dir_1
`-- dir_2
```

Let's suppose that `root` is the owner and the group is `some_group`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root       some_group 4096 Apr 16 13:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 some_user  some_user  4096 Apr 16 13:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       some_group 4096 Apr 16 13:38 dir_1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root       some_group 4096 Apr 16 13:38 dir_2
```

Now, I want a user who is member of `some_group` not to be able to remove `dir_1` and `dir_2`, which I believe I've guaranteed by setting them to `755`, but at the same time I need this user to be able to write inside `test`, but without being able to delete the whole `test` directory. Is there any way of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realize that in Unix file systems, you don't need write permission on the target to delete an entry, just on the containing directory.

If you want to protect the directory `test`, set the permissions on the parent of `test`.

If you want to allow users to create and delete their own files, set the permissions on `test` to `1777`. The high bit is called the sticky bit.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick (I didn't know about the sticky bit).